# How to translating OMI PROFOZ ozone layer HDF5 to GeoTIFF?

Tags: raster, r, gdal-translate, hdf5

I studied the article 'Lower tropospheric ozone over India and its linkage to the South Asian monsoon' and the article 'Validation of 10-year SAO OMI ozone profile (PROFOZ) product using Aura MLS  measurements'. Thereby, I'm looking for tropospheric ozone, and I found OMPROFOZ data in the GODDARD SPACE data catalog.

I'd like to convert a subset from HDF5 to GeoTIFF. Thereby I'm trying to convert the OMI PROFOZ ozone layer provided in HDF5 to the GeoTIFF format using gdal_translate() in the R environment.

I found the full name of the variable is HDFEOS/SWATHS/OMI_Vertical_Ozone_Profile/Data_Fields/O3TroposphericColumn.

The data is OMPROFOZ ozone layer downloaded from this link
[clic here](https://avdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/data/satellite/Aura/OMI/V03/L2/OMPROFOZ/)

An example of the HDF5 file can be [download here -](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SetKPc6UPMaMSvVmlhxukfQ_RmH3m20m/view?usp=sharing)

I already tried gdal_translate() to extract the subsect and convert the HDF5 to GeoTIFF in the R environment, which gives me this result:
[image: OMPROFOZ O3 process in R platform]

However, this result don't match with the cordinate of my shape file, insted i ploted it in panoply platform
My code:

```
library(gdalUtilities)
library(gdalUtils)
library(raster)
fname = 'G:\\O3_Data\\OMI-Aura_L2-PROFOZ_2010m0701t0533-o31702_v003-2013m0108t100600.he5'
gdalinfo(fname)
sds <- get_subdatasets(fname)
sds
gdal_translate(sds[26], dst_dataset = "G:\\O3_Data\\O3_20100701.tif",a_ullr=c(), format="GTiff")

gdalwarp("G:\\O3_Data\\O3_20100701.tif",dstfile="G:\\O3_Data\\O3_20100701_project_7.tif",
         t_srs="EPSG:3410",
         # t_srs='EPSG:4326',
         output_Raster=TRUE,
         overwrite=TRUE,verbose=TRUE)


rastt <- raster("G:\\O3_Data\\O3_20100701_project_7.tif")
plot(rastt)
extent(rastt)=c(xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90)
plot(rastt)

asia <- shapefile('D:\\other2020_22\\shapfile\\Asis_final_export\\asia_final.shp')
# add polygons
plot(asia, add=TRUE, axes=F)
```

My shapefile- [download here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HA_cycy-MdrRVBsybR00INxkNdz0UP9Z/view?usp=sharing)

panoply plot- [image: view]

Answer (score 2):

I think its because you are falsely assigning it a new extent at this point:

```
extent(rastt)=c(xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90)
```

Its projected extent in its coordinate system (EPSG:3410) is:

```
> extent(rastt)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -8403326 
xmax       : 14120337 
ymin       : -7287267 
ymax       : 7264838
```

Which I can make into points and then translate to lat-long:

```
ep = st_as_sf(data.frame(matrix(extent(rastt), ncol=2)), coords=1:2, crs=3410)
st_transform(ep, 4326)
# Simple feature collection with 2 features and 0 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -87.26098 ymin: -82.11291 xmax: 146.627 ymax: 80.92823
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#                     geometry
# 1 POINT (-87.26098 -82.11291)
# 2    POINT (146.627 80.92823)
```

Which will probably have the effect of misaligning it with the world. Not only will it mess up the apparent range, but the raster still thinks it is in EPSG:3410, and these are now coordinates in metres.

So, I don't know why you reassign it to an invalid extent, but if you don't do that then it looks fine. Have tested in R and QGIS.

If you really want it in lat-long, then `gdalwarp` again to EPSG:4326 or use `raster::projectRaster

```
rw = projectRaster(rastt, crs="+init=epsg:4326")
```

Comment: I tried many times to reproject (raster::projectRaster) the raster to the EPSG:4326 projection system, but the raster O3 layer doesn't line up with the shape file. instead, panoply plots the O3 data perfectly with all projections.